# How to add the facebook "Add friend button" to my website?

Tags: facebook

(sorry if my question is not in the right place)

I'm creating a website where people can login to my website with thier facebook accounts! They join my website because they want to get new facebook friends. the members of my website all want new friends requests. and everyone of them can add the link to his facebook profile so other members can add him as a friens. by clicking the "Add friend" button in front of every member's profile ON MY WEBSITE a friend request is sent to the owner of that profile!
My clear question is: is it possible to make that Add Friend button appear on my website in front of every profile??

Thanks fro the answers

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot send Friend Request with the Facebook API, and there is no Social Plugin for this either. The possibility was removed with v2.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/friends/v2.0

> This was removed as of Graph API version 2.0